# Ajuda com esquema do banco de dados

Tags: php, banco-de-dados, estrutura-de-dados, mysql

Estou desenvolvendo um sistema de controle de pedidos, e estou finalizando, porém agora me deparei com um problema no esquema da parte de pagamentos:

Estou ligando o `id_pedido` com os pagamentos, porém, quando o pedido custa `R$48,90` e a pessoa paga `R$50,00`, eu tenho que dar `R$1,10` de troco, estou salvando o `R$50,00` no banco de dados para depois subtrair com o valor total, para na nota sair o valor do troco, até ai tudo certo, mas quando for gerar os relatórios isso vai me dar muita dor de cabeça, e não consigo pensar noutra maneira de fazer essa parte do trocado, pois precisa ficar salvo na nota trocado.
A pessoa pode pagar mais de uma maneira, vamos supor dinheiro e cartão.

Comment: Nota fiscal? PHP? Ai!. Não vejo problema algum aí, exveto usar a ferramenta errada para o problema. A não ser que o problema não seja esse e não esteja nada claro.

Comment: Problema está mais em lógica do que em programação. Se existe mais de uma forma de pagamento então você tem um relacionamento 1 para N ( 1 pedido para N formas de pagamento), só inserir na tabela de relação de Pedido e Tipo de pagamento o valor pago em cada forma. Somar tudo e subtrair do valor total do pedido.

Answer (score 0):

Imagino que na sua tabela de pagamento vá ter o id do pedido e o valor pago, dessa forma você já consegue saber a diferença a ser devolvida.
Porém, você pode incluir se for o caso uma coluna na sua tabela de pagamento referente a esse tipo de diferença.
Ou ná própria query pra gerar o relatório pode ser feito a conta exemplo:

```
select pedido.valortotal, pagamento.valorpago, (pedido.valortotal - pagamento.valorpago) as troco
from pedido
inner join pagamento on pedido.id = pagamento.idpedido
```

Comment: então ,na verdade o valor eu coloco pela tabela de peças do pedido, pois cada peça pode ter um valor separado,e para pegar o valor total do pedido eu itero em todas as peças do mesmo pedido e faço a soma.terei que criar uma coluna e colocar o valor total do pedido então?

Comment: e sobre pegar o valor total de renda nos mês vamos supor, eu vou ter que pegar todos os pedidos e verificar na tabela de pagamentos, e fizer um if else?

Comment: O ideal é que na tabela de pedidos tenha o valor total do pedido já considerando o preço dos produtos.